# Passing some relations of a table by variant ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, relation, variant

I'm not sure if it's possible to do this but I'm importing different CSVs into multiple mySQL tables so I use multiple functions to do this import.
how can I change something like:

```
@page = @book.pages.first
```

to this:

```
relation = pages

@page = @book.relation.first
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch the relations dynamically, you can do it like this:

```
relation = :pages  # or 'pages'
@page = @book.send(relation).first
```